# Resources to learn second quantization formalism and how to implement it in code for quantum/computational chemistry research

Tags: quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I want to know what are some useful and practical resources to learn the formalism of second quantization as it pertains to fermions to be used in solving Quantum Chemistry problems. I am particularly asking for resources that go beyond the symbolic formalism and have guides/examples on how to implement the second quantization ideas in code (regardless of comp. language).
The pink book: Molecular Electronic-Structure Theory from Helgaker is a good start on the topic with all the formalism but I am looking for other resources with coding examples or practical implemmentations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check out any code set that implements configuration interaction wave function methods.  The Journal of Chemical Physics published an open-access article reviewing the state of ab-initio software, and it lists code sets that use CI.

 https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/5.0023185

Notably, NWChem uses the second quantization approach and is described in this open resource paper:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.01131.pdf

Finding algorithms to rapidly create valid CI expansions was a big research area in the late 1970's, and the Graphical Unitary Group Approach was created.  There are several open source packages that use the GUGA, including GAMESS.
 https://www.msg.chem.iastate.edu/gamess/download.html 
  You can get GAMESS by requesting access and registering.  You could then review the implementation assuming a basic knowledge of FORTRAN.